# jQuery Sortable - iFrame SRC not in DOM

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have widgets/portlets similar to

```
<div id="100" class="portlets">
     <iframe src="widgets/widget1_iframe.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

Within each iFrame is another iFrame. I can add multiple widgets/portlets and order them.

I have a script which (for each change) gets the SRC of the initial iFrame (so in this case **widgets/widget1_iframe.html**) and the SRC of the iFrame within the iFrame (in my testing version, it alerts the user).

So using the example before, let's say I add a new one to have something similar to

```
<div id="200" class="portlets">
     <iframe src="widgets/widget2_iframe.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

I then decide to move the second one above the first one. My script correctly shows **widgets/widget2_iframe.html** but then displays nothing for the iframe within the iframe. It then shows **widgets/widget1_iframe.html** correctly and also the iFrame within that iframe as well.

I did a check and the iFrame (within the iframe) within the widget/portlet is not available to the DOM.

So basically, if I had 100 portlets that I added and moved one, it would show me all the correct information apart from the iframe within the iframe of the widget/portlet that has been moved. Below is the **stop** event of my **sortable** function

```
stop: function (event, ui) {
    var sortorder = '';
    $('.' + opts.columnClass).each(function () {
        var itemorder = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        sortorder += itemorder.toString();
    });

    var substr = sortorder.split(',');

    jQuery.each(substr, function () {
            $.post("process.php", {
                widget: $('div#' + this + ' div.widgetcontent iframe').attr("src"),
                iframe: $('div#' + this + ' div.widgetcontent iframe').contents().find('iframe').attr("src")

            }, function (data) {
                alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
            });

    });
```

Essentially - the value for iFrame is not being passed for the widget/portlet that has been moved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put a delay straight after `stop: function(event, ui) {` of 1 second which seems to sort it